# AlertView inside alertView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

A button from the first alert executes the second alert which is basically a confirmation to call someone. I don't get any errors but it doesn't work.
When I press on the second alert the Call button it crashes

```
-(void) alertView: (UIAlertView *) alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{

     NSString *buttonString = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
     if ([buttonString isEqualToString:@"Phone"]) 
     {    
          UIAlertView *alert2 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Notice!" message:@"You are about to call .... Do you wish to continue?" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Call", nil];    
          [alert2 show];

          if ([buttonString isEqualToString:@"Call"]){

              [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://12345678"]]];

          }

          if([buttonString isEqualToString:@"Website"]){

              [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"website"]];
          }

          if ([buttonString isEqualToString:@"Facebook"]){

             [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.facebook.com/groups/..../"]];

          }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You assigned to delegate as a nil in second alertview. That's why the `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` delegate method is not called in second time. So you should assign to delegate as a `self`.

```
    -(void) alertView: (UIAlertView *) alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

                  NSString *buttonString = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

                  if([buttonString isEqualToString:@"Phone"]) {

                  UIAlertView *alert2 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Notice!" message:@"You are about to call .... Do you wish to continue?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Call", nil];
                  [alert2 show];
                  }

                  if([buttonString isEqualToString:@"Call"]){

                     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://12345678"]]];
                  } 

                  if([buttonString isEqualToString:@"Website"]){

                    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"website"]];
                  }


                  if([buttonString isEqualToString:@"Facebook"]){

                     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.facebook.com/groups/..../"]];
                  }

 }
```

I think it will be helpful to you.

Comment: I separated if conditions. Please check it.

Comment: Tested on my end - it works. You got other problems then, my friend.

Comment: Did you tried it on the actual device? It works on simulator but not on actual device..

Answer (score 0):

Launch the second alert with a delay. Problem is - alert needs some time to hide itself, before any new alerts can appear, thus directly calling second one will not work.

try this for example:

```
- (void) alertView: (UIAlertView *) alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    NSString *buttonString = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    if ([buttonString isEqualToString:@"Phone"]) 
    {
        [self performSelector:@selector(callSecondAlertView) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
    }
}

- (void)callSecondAlertView
{
    //show new alert view
    UIAlertView *alert2 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Notice!" message:@"You are about to call .... Do you wish to continue?" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Call", nil];

    [alert2 show];

    [alert2 release];
}
```

If not working, or too long delay - play with `afterDelay:` value.

Comment: now it calls right away without poping the second alert. i tried up to 5 sec.. the way i had it, it did bring up the second alert but did not perform the call..

Comment: ok, have you tried if that call even works? 

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://12345678"]]];

Answer (score 0):

got it! for some reason the [[[alertView subviews] objectAtIndex:6] setBackgroundColor... for the fisrt alertView buttons i had interferes with the second alertView functionality. xcode though did not direct me directly to the problem until i updated xcode to 4.4.1

Answer (score 0):

Use the `alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:` delegate method instead of the `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` delegate method. The former is called after the alert is gone. This make more sense when you want to show a second based on the tapped button of the first alert view.

Also give tag to UIAlertview objects.